# chef-solo with docker: Prevent services from starting during build

Tags: chef, docker, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to reuse existing cookbooks within docker containers, but most recipes will start the service during the chef client run (e.g. tomcat, apache2). As chef-solo runs during image creation the chef run will simply fail.

How can I prevent a cookbook from starting a service?

I am using the following Dockerfile

```
FROM jr42/chef-solo-centos

ADD chef /chef
RUN cd /chef && /opt/chef/embedded/bin/berks vendor /chef/cookbooks
RUN chef-solo -N mynode -c /chef/solo.rb -j /chef/solo.json
```

tomcat in my runbook (solo.json):

```
{
  "tomcat": {
    "base_version": ""
  },
  "run_list": [ "recipe[tomcat]" ]
}
```

and Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"
metadata
cookbook 'tomcat'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using the cookbook with unmodified attributes, and the default behavior of the tomcat cookbook is to run a 'default' base tomcat instance.

Refer to the resource declared [here](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat/blob/19f07e453a7f70884da4e654df8ce2397eb83664/recipes/default.rb#L71-L80) and the attribute setting [here](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/tomcat/blob/19f07e453a7f70884da4e654df8ce2397eb83664/attributes/default.rb#L49).

You should be able to update your `solo.json` to override this attribute:

```
{
  "tomcat": {
    "base_version": "",
    "run_base_instance": false
  },
  "run_list": [ "recipe[tomcat]" ]
}
```

And you shouldn't have the service automatically start.

Alternately, you could look at the [chef-container](https://docs.getchef.com/containers.html) project documentation and see if this maps to a better build procedure for your containerized application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It solves the issue with the tomcat cookbook. Is there no general way to prevent service start, stops and restarts? I have similar issues with almost every cookbook during "docker build". This includes chef-container

Comment: @jr42 Many cookbook maintainers assume that the desired state of a recipe is that a service be started when the "thing" is configured - not exactly docker-friendly. You _could_ try looking at something like chef-rewind's `unwind` to remove particular resources - but this is a tricky thing to get right.